# ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com after heroku run python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, heroku, migrate

Has anyone got this error:

```
ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com
rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com:5000
```

while running

`heroku run python manage.py migrate` ?

Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Comment: I remember seeing this error somewhere, it turned out to be caused by you not being connected to the internet, so the CLI cant connect to the heroku servers. I think the fix was to try running it until it succeeds.

Comment: @N.Ivanov I am behind a proxy. Could that be the reason? And if so how can I by pass it?

Also if I run it over and over I get this:

`Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos`

Comment: It might be possible but sadly I cannot help you with that. I would suggest you to open up the heroku console on your heroku dashboard and try running the command from there? As far as I remember I think there was a heroku console on the dashboard. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Did you solve the issue by using the heroku console from the dashboard?

Comment: Yes I did. I think it worked although I still get the same errors using linux terminal. Thanks.

Comment: I will post the solution as an answer and if you could mark it as accepted solution for future people visiting this question to easily resolve their issue? Thanks and I'm glad that this helped you!

Answer (score 6):

The error is because the user (or the CLI) cannot connect to the heroku servers, as is your case being behind a proxy. The fast and easy solution would be to go over to your Heroku Dashboard, and open up a Heroku Console there, then simply run your code from there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with a Rails app on Heroku.

Running `heroku console --app AppName` in my local terminal I got: `ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com`. This happened when I was trying to access our production app, but I also got the same response when trying to access the console on any of our Heroku development servers.

I've been working on this app for a year and this is the first time this has happened.

I went to the relevant app on the Heroku dashboard, clicked the `Run console` option, but then didn't actually run anything. I then tried `heroku console --app AppName` on my local terminal again and it worked as it should. The time between first getting the error and then it working was around 10 minutes. I'm not sure if interacting with the Heroku dashboard did anything, or if it was just that something was wrong at the time and it got sorted out when I tried a few minutes later.